# Is helping others grasp difficult ideas, concepts or theories not considered giving an answer?

Tags: discussion, soft-question

I know you could just leave a comment, but not in this case I couldn't. I just found this awesome app while researching on my passion, physics. I stumbled across [a question about time dilation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/90745/gravity-on-the-international-space-station-general-relativity-perspective/192950#192950), not the easiest concept to grasp, and a commenter had his own question within his comment, just wasn't  looking at the answer correctly. So, I stared at this screen, going to different links forever and it was impossible since I have no, "points", since I just signed up. I clicked on, "answer" and FINALLY, it let me speak. Intellectual curiosity is an amazing thing. Well, next thing I know, I got my first comment and flag all in one. All you scientists know how important it is for more and more people to have a scientific world view if we're planning on living on this planet for much longer. So I gave him an easy layman's answer to fully understand the answer.  We all know you don't have to know the math to have that burning curiosity of the unknown, and the want to understand and wrap your mind around things you had no idea was wrappable. I believe I gave this user a just as valid answer as the mathematical answer. Do you?

Comment: The way to progress on this site , i.e. to get enough reputation not to have difficulties, is two fold. a) you can ask questions about some physics subject or b) answer questions on physics subjects ( not just comment) or both.

Comment: @Nicolle: Your question has been moved to Meta.Physics.SE, which is where discussions about the site occur. Here, votes (up or down) do not affect your reputation but represent agreement (upvote) or disagreement (downvote) with your statement.

Answer (score 4):

Anything which answers the posted question should be posted as an answer; anything which does not, should not. It's that simple. (Although there *are* cases in which it's debatable whether a post answers the question.)

The post you made [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/192950/124) (which I'm guessing is the one you are asking about) does not answer the question, and should not have been posted as an answer. The fact that you addressed your post to someone who is not the asker is a dead giveaway.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are making a non-issue an issue. I probably guess that you have answered to the asker who haven't actually asked the question & a question that actually wasn't matching the OP's question. You have every right to explain the physics to a layman _ we are not having a problem with that, nor we discourage anyone to answer anyone's question. However, since the question was not the same to that of OP, you could probably comment to him/her; oh! you are a new user - then you have to *bid* your time:)

Comment: Okay obviously you're the one who likes issues. And it I'm just talking. I've never been on this site before, ever. I found it by researching the topic of that question I stumbled upon. I noticed that someone didn't understand the answer the math equation gave and so I explained it. Now that I've been bitched at over and over again I realize this place is nothing like reddit, which is what I was thinking based on the one page I was at. I was under the impression that it was a place to talk about interests and/or professions. everybody freaking out about a discussion I was trying to have.

Comment: It's clearly not a place to discuss stuff, everybody takes it so seriously. I don't get what is so bad about explaining something to a side commenter through an answer when I wasn't "allowed"  to comment. Here's some basic psychology: since I'm a human being, I saw someone that needed some help understanding something, and since I figured an easy way for them to get it, and I get so excited to talk about physics, I'm going to school for 8 years for it for God's sake. OF COURSE I'M GONNA FIND ANY WAY I CANNOT TO EXPLAIN IT TO THEM! I have a human brain, and a very strong passion,youdothemath

Comment: @Nicolle Dransfeldt: I on behalf of the community apologise for anything that has vexed you, but there are some rules which you have to follow here. I am reiterating that we don't discourage anyone to ask nor anyone to answer, after all we are here for that. Just answer one good question or ask some & earn the point to help those sideby-commenters. This is quite easy as there are many naive questions to be answered for earning decent votes. So, I don't think this predicament can make you hate such an excellent community:>

Comment: @Nicolle Dransfeldt : It is not your fault though. If anyone has problem , he can ask his very own question. If you remain here, you will comprehend easily why everyone should follow the rules of the site; after all they are for the sake of the development & well-being of the site-the community. Thank you , nevertheless, for sharing your feedback.